# Log4j in Unit Testing Environment

Tags: java, junit, log4j

I am performing JUnit Testing and receiving log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (class .. ) error when I run test class(s).

Log4j properties file is present inside my folder root directory.
This code seems to work but why doesn't log4j picked up automatically.

```java
package com.folio3.automation;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class TestClass {

    static {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestClass.class);

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        LOG.info("test 1 called ");
        Assert.assertEquals(true, false);


    }

}
```

Do I have to call BasicConfigurator.configure(); in every class or Base class ?
Is there any way to achieve?

Comment: What does the `CLASSPATH` look like as log4j.properties must be on your `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: log4j.properties file is under my application root directory.

Comment: ... which is not the same as your CLASSPATH; your CLASSPATH is set by the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or the `-cp` parameter to the JVM. Try adding your application root directory to your VM start command and your problem should disappear

Comment: Thanks for the help @hd1, I have just tried to put my properties file in src folder and it works fine.

Comment: I posted it as an answer, would appreciate it if you would accept/vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your application root directory to your VM start command and your problem will disappear.